# when i want change get become post it not work well

Tags: laravel, routes

i have problem when i want to change Get become Post.

when i use Get i can get the data

but when use post i cannot get the data please help me

i have change the web.php or routes become Post but i cannot get my data when i use post

i have change get become post in my web.php in my laravel. but the result not the same

this is my code in laravel

```
public function getHistoryEvent(Request $request) {
$consumer_data = array();
$consumer_data['consumer_key'] = request()->header('consumer-key');
$consumer_data['consumer_secret'] = request()->header('consumer-secret');
$consumer_data['consumer_nonce']      = request()->header('consumer-nonce');
$consumer_data['consumer_device_id']  = request()->header('consumer-device-id');
$consumer_data['consumer_url'] = __FUNCTION__;
$authController = new AppSettingController();
$authenticate = $authController->apiAuthenticate($consumer_data);

        if($authenticate==1 || $authenticate==0){
        $event = DB::table('u_history_events')
                    ->select('u_history_events.history_events_id','u_history_events.events_image','u_history_events.events_description','u_history_events.date_create')
                    ->where('u_history_events.events_id',$request->events_id)
                    ->where('u_history_events.kode_customers',$request->kode_customer)
                    ->get();

            $responseData = array('success'=>'1', 'data'=>$event,  'message'=>"Success.");
        }else{
            $responseData = array('success'=>'0', 'data'=>array(),  'message'=>"Unauthenticated call.");
        }
        $orderResponse = json_encode($responseData);
        print $orderResponse;

    }
```

when use get i can get this data the result are :

```
{"success": "1",
    "data": [
        {"history_events_id": 2,
            "events_image": "",
            "events_description": "",
            "date_create": "2019-05-11 10:59:01"
        },
        {
            "history_events_id": 3,
            "events_image": "",
            "events_description": "",
            "date_create": "2019-05-11 11:59:35"
        }
       }
```

but when i use post i only get

```
{"success":"1","data":[],"message":"Success."}
```

Comment: You should probably remove the `java` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I am no Laravel expert, but according to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing), looks like you have to explicitly define a route for the `POST` verb to your controller's method:

```
Route::post($uri, $callback);
```

Or according to [Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers) docs:

```
// change <your path here> and <your method name> to your desired path and
// method names
Route::get('<your path here>', 'AppSettingController@<your method name>');
```

I also recommend you to read MDN's [An overview of HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview).